# how to calculate the time in android

Tags: android, time

I am trying to calculate the pace value in my app. For that the formula I am using is

> pace = time / distance traveled.

When a button is clicked I start calculating the distance I am traveling, but I don't know how to get the time in minutes, exactly from when the button was clicked.

Please help me friends.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current time in milliseconds with `System.currentTimeMillis();` Then you can convert it pretty much any time base you want. You'll need a base from the moment your activity was started. Storing the `System.currentTimeMillis();` at the beginning of the activity and doing simple subtraction would work.

Answer (score 2):

When handling time and timing in Android, be sure to understand the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html